# can i call super() from a derived class of a private field located in the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

i have 2 classes in separate files.

```
public class A 
{
   private int _x;

   public A (int x)
   { 
      _x = x;
   }

   public int getX()
   {
      return _x;
   }

   public int doubleX()
   {
     return 2 * getX();
  }
}

public class B extends A 
{
    private int _x;

    public B(int xA, int xB)
    {
       super(xA);
       _x = xB;
    }
}
```

main method in a separate file...

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A a = new A(1);
    A b = new B(2,22);
    System.out.println(b.doubleX());
}
```

is it ok to have the same name. its called hiding right?
but class B can't inherit a private field from A
its ok to call super in the constructor of B like shown above?

i have read a lot of articles and studied of inheritance.
just want to make things clear as possible.

Comment: Note: It doesn't matter in the slightest whether they're in different files or not.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. There are two different `_x` fields, one for each class, and each class only accesses its own one. None of that has any effect on being able to call parent methods (including `super()`) from the derived class.

Comment: Your code is fine.  This is one reason to make your attributes `private`.  It helps avoid a lot of bad confusion in cases such like this.  I'm not sure what you mean with “is it ok” though.  I guess it depends on what you are trying to do.  At least from a compiler's point of view, there is nothing wrong about it.

Answer (score 2):

> its called hiding right?

No, `A`'s `_x` is only hidden from `B` because it's `private` in `A`. It could be `protected` or `public` and therefore accessible to `B` (as `super._x`, since you've shadowed it with a declaration in `B`) and it wouldn't change anything.

> but class `B` cant inherit a private field from `A` its ok to call `super` in the constructor of `B` like shown above?

`B` can't *see* the private `_x` in `A`, because it's private, but it *does* inherit it. `B` can also have its own `_x` (private or otherwise), and the two do not conflict at all — the `B` instance has both. Remember, `B` *is an* `A`.

This might help clarify things for you:

```
public class Example {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        (new B(42, 67)).show();
    }

    static class A
    {
        private int x;

        protected A(int arg) {
            this.x = arg;
        }

        protected int getX() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }

    static class B extends A
    {
        private int x;

        public B(int arg1, int arg2) {
            super(arg1);
            this.x = arg2;
        }

        public void show() {
            System.out.println("this.getX() = " + this.getX() + ", this.x = " + this.x);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of running that is:

```
this.getX() = 42, this.x = 67
```

As you can see, the instance has both `x` members, `A$x` and `B$x`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder , this.getX() is the same as super(getX()) ? and also. this is vaild ? --> super.getX()

Comment: @idandi: *"this.getX() is the same as super(getX()) ?"* No, `super(getX())` would be trying to call the superclass's constructor passing in the result of calling `getX()`. *"and also. this is vaild ? --> super.getX()"* Yes, that's valid. It's how you call the superclass's version of a method if you've overridden it. No need for it in the above, though, because `B` doesn't override `getX`.